Pick<> doesn't accept the same input as Omit<>
For context, I wanted to define a set of possible string values as a type. Then, I wanted to restrict this set to include only some of these values, using Pick<> to ensure I remain resilient to any future additions.
In the TypeScript documentation here, it’s mentioned that Omit is the opposite of Pick, so I was surprised to encounter an error when attempting to use Pick instead of Omit for this use case.
I managed to get it working with Extract instead of Pick, but I would appreciate some clarification.
Here’s a minimal reproducible example:
const legalEntity = ['individual', 'company', 'ngo'] as const;
type LegalEntity = (typeof legalEntity)[number];

// Works
type NgoOnly = Omit<LegalEntity, 'individual' | 'company'>;

// Doesn't work, surprisingly
type IndividualOrCompanyPick = Pick<LegalEntity, 'individual' | 'company'>;

// Works as expected
type IndividualOrCompanyExclude = Extract<
  LegalEntity,
  'ngo'
>;

Questions:

Why does Pick not work as expected here?
Is Extract the best approach for restricting a set of values from a union type in this case?

Any insights would be helpful!
I tried the above code, I expected Pick working in a similar manner of Omit, but it didn't. Then I used Extract

Pick/Omit are for when the target is an object type and you're manipulating properties, Extract/Exclude are for when the target is a union type and you're manipulating membership in the union. It doesn't work when you use the wrong one, and it does work when you use the correct one.

// Works does it? Playground Link

If you look closely at NgoOnly from your example you'll see that it's basically all the members of a string object, and not the literal ngo which is what I think you wanted.  For that you'd use Exclude or Extract.

• Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

(see prev comment) • Please [edit] to fix your example to be a [mre] where the only issues are the ones you're asking about. Your NgoOnly (as prev comments mention) is not anything useful, and indeed, it really seems like you're misusing both Pick and Omit. There is a version of this question where you pass in object types and ask why Pick errors for unknown keys, but that's not what you seem to be asking with this example.

As stated by @jared-smith in their comment, Pick<T, Keys> and Omit<T, Keys> work on objects while, Extract<T, Members> and Exclude<T, Members> works on union types such as LegalEntity from your example.
Your example will work if you use Exclude or Extract.  In the example below,  Extract is used to create a new type that ends up being the literal of ngo.  Then Exlude is used to create another type from LegalEntity that is everything not in the first type that was created.
const legalEntity = ['individual', 'company', 'ngo'] as const;
type LegalEntity = (typeof legalEntity)[number];

type NgoOnly = Extract<LegalEntity, 'ngo'>; // 'ngo'.
type IndividualOrCompany = Exclude<LegalEntity, NgoOnly>; // 'individual' | 'company'

